# RewriteRule with an IPv6 IP address does not work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ipv6

I am having problems to proxy requestions inside a IPv6 address.

On .htaccess/apache2.conf, I have it:

`RewriteRule (.*) http://18.4.15.8:80/path/$1 [P,L]`

It works fine, because it is a IPv4 address.
But, it does not works:

`RewriteRule (.*) http://[27:ec:20:22:15::d3]:80/path/$1 [P,L]`

Why?

Error Log:

> Proxy Error
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /index.html.
>
> Reason: URI cannot be parsed: http://%5b27:ec:20:22:15::d3%5d:80/path/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of `[` & `]`. Thay are usually not allowed in a URL and so the server is escaping it to `%b5`and `%5d`. To prevent this use the NE Flag in your Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://[27:ec:20:22:15::d3]:80/path/$1 [NE,P,L]
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: This simple solution solved my problem and IPv6 has worked fine. I've searched every page on google, but nothing found was explicity on it. It was a really simple solution. Thank you. Regards