# Redirect domain with .htaccess to IPv6 address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ipv6

**EDIT 2019-11-26:**
Thanks Harry for the comment, I didn't find this question

I tried to redirect from my domain on my webhost to my home IP address. (for accessing my NAS)

At home I have an IPv6 adress only. The IPv4 address is going through a NAT at my ISP. (known as dual stack lite)

I know, it should be possible to use my IPv6 adress with a name server. However I like to use my webhost for convenience reasons.

Redirecting to an IPv4 address works with .htaccess.
However, following .htaccess code for IPv6 doesn't work.

```
Redirect / http://[MY-IPV6-HOME-ADDRESS]/
```

I used the [] brackets, because it is used for IPv6 address in web browser. It seems to be wrong for .htaccess.

Do you know a solution for .htaccess for IPv6 redirect?
Or redirect in PHP or html to IPv6 address?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609891/rewriterule-with-an-ipv6-ip-address-does-not-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RewriteRule with an IPv6 IP address does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609891/rewriterule-with-an-ipv6-ip-address-does-not-work)